# Почему котлеты рубленые?

Tags: значение-слов

Есть котлеты отбивные, а есть рубленые. Почему их так называют?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мясо давным-давно ножом уже никто не "рубит", разве что для экзотики. Для "рубленых" котлет ныне именно *прокручивают* через мясорубку. Вот только после прокрутки мясо как раз и называется *рубленым*. Что делать, традиция, мясорубки как раз и появилсиь чтобы избавить повара от необходимости работать ножом. 
Да и само слово *мясо**рубка*** вполне себе говорящее.

> а рубят — то есть, мелко нарезают

Во-первых - не нарезают, а именно рубят. Это разные вещи. Режут - хлеб, сыр, колбасу.
Рубят - яйца, овощи, картофель в салат. Когда-то - и мясо.

А во-вторых, вы в современных условиях этот процесс, *рубки мяса ножом*, реально наблюдали?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что мясо для таких котлет не прокручивают через мясорубку, а рубят — то есть, мелко нарезают. Получается не фарш, а маленькие кусочки мяса, из которых, собственно, котлета и состоит.
Отсюда — рубленные.
А отбивные — соответственно, кусок мяса отбивается специальной колотушкой, чтобы был мягче. Но мясо при этом не режется.

Comment: Для @jedi "Потому что мясо для таких котлет не прокручивают через мясорубку, а рубят — то есть, мелко нарезают." Отсюда - РЕЗАНЫЕ. Но так не говорят, хотя готовят и так. 

В старину повар рубил кусок мяса в фарш, используя два острых ножа, и орудовал ими как будто бил в барабан, то есть наносил удары, рубил, поворачивая время от времени разделочную доску. Получался именно рубленый фарш, а не резаное мясо. Теперь так РУБЯТ фарш только в очень дорогих ресторанах, где обещают все старинное, натуральное.А в основном повара используют мясоРУБКУ. И только так делают рубленые котлеты.